# How do I temporarily enable mysql.general_log in AWS Aurora Serverless V2?

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-aurora

I am trying to debug an issue and I just need to see the general log of a mysql instance.  Is there any way of temporarily enabling or routing the logs to a file/cloudwatch for a minute or so?

Attempting to do `SET global general_log = 1;` yields

> SQL Error [1227] [42000]: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
> Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
> Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation

I tried to do export to CloudWatch logs in the console, but that would only export if there's a log file I think and there isn't any.

Comment: the net of it is we can simply enable it using db parameters I'll post a proper answer later.